# how to detect mousemove if svg is behind another element

Tags: svg, d3.js

How can I call the `d3.mouse` **mousemove** event when the svg is behind another element (hovertip  element)?

Comment: Any codes for us to base on ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't get any mouse events for elements that are behind other elements unless the elements in front have the property `pointer-events` set to `none`.